# How to get DS.find().then() to be called when using angular-data-mocks

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, sinon, angular-data

I've been trying to test a service I'm writing that makes use of angular-data data stores and can't get it to call the callback passed to `then()`. I've got a basic example of what I'm trying to do below and what I expect to happen.  Can anybody shed any light on what it is I'm doing wrong and why this doesn't work as expected?

I'd expect this test to pass and print `this is called` to the console. It does neither, failing with "expected false to be true".

```
describe('usage of expectFind', function(){
    beforeEach(function (done) {
        inject(function (_DS_) {
            DS = _DS_;
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should call the callback passed to then', function(done){
        DS.expectFind('foo', 1).respond([{a: 'thing'}])

        var called = false;
        DS.find('foo', 1).then(function(aFoo){
            console.log('this is called');
            called = true;
            done();
        });
        expect(called).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, I tried to add this with the `angular-data-mocks` tag but it doesn't exist and I don't have enough rep to create it, if someone could add it that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

OK we worked it out, we need to call `DS.flush()` before the expectation.  This is what actually triggers the callbacks to be invoked.

```
describe('usage of expectFind', function(){
beforeEach(function (done) {
    inject(function (_DS_) {
        DS = _DS_;
        done();
    });
});

it('should call the callback passed to then', function(done){
    DS.expectFind('foo', 1).respond([{a: 'thing'}])

    var called = false;
    DS.find('foo', 1).then(function(aFoo){
        console.log('this is called');
        called = true;
        done();
    });


    // this is what's missing
    DS.flush();

    expect(called).toBe(true);
});
```

});